# Displaying data in a datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid, dataset

I am trying to display these xml strings in a datagrid. I don't know much about datasets, but it does not seem to keep the data previously entered. Here is my code.

C#:

```
 while (reader.Read())
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string rdr = reader[i].ToString();

                    dataList.Add(rdr);


                    string column = reader.GetName(i);
                    const string xmlAttributeFormat = "{0} = \"{1}\" ";
                    xmlString = xmlString + String.Format(xmlAttributeFormat, column, dataList[i]);


                }

                string FinalXMLString = "<row " + xmlString + " />";
                StringReader streamreader = new System.IO.StringReader(FinalXMLString);
                XmlTextReader xmlreader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(streamreader);
                dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                dataSet.ReadXml(xmlreader);
                xmlString = "";
                dataList.Clear();
                FinalXMLString = "";

            }
```

I have a while loop that is going through the query and then a for loop to put the values in a list. This is working perfectly. The data is then being put into a dataset which is then binded to the datagrid. The only problem is it only shows the data from the last line read from the query. How do I make it show all of the rows from the query in the datagrid? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Look at your code you are in a While Loop and you are creating a new instance for these 3 lines `StringReader streamreader = new System.IO.StringReader(FinalXMLString);
                XmlTextReader xmlreader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader(streamreader);
                dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();` Clean up and or Refactor the code

Comment: by putting `dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();` out of your while

Comment: @Natrium Now it just puts the first row in the datagrid

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (reader.Read())
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string rdr = reader[i].ToString();

                    dataList.Add(rdr);


                    string column = reader.GetName(i);
                  }

           }

Display_Grid(myGrid,dataList)




public static void Display_Grid(DataGrid d, List<string> S1)
            {
                ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                DataColumn cl = new DataColumn(column, typeof(string));
                cl.MaxLength = 200;
                dt.Columns.Add(cl);



                int i = 0;
                foreach (string s in S1)
                {
                    DataRow rw = dt.NewRow();

                    rw["Description"] = S1[i];

                    i++;
                }

                d.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].AsDataView();
            }
```

you pass the name of your datagrid (d) and the string List (s1) as parameters ad inside the code you define the name of the columhn header of to be shown (I have written Description).

In your case S1=datalist.
 if datalist contains e.g 3 elements then the method will iterate through those and produce 3 rows...

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is going on in your code a bit more.

Comment: I need to use the xml strings though.. I think that is what is giving me the most trouble.

Comment: why you need that for adding more columns??

Comment: I don't need to add columns. All of the rows produced by the query are not being placed in the datagrid. Only the last row is showing.

Comment: have you checked that the query sends multiple results?

Comment: Yes it does :) and it is added to my datalist correctly and everything,

Comment: so you are running my code and returns only last line again, correct?